# Problema python, hacer semi transparente progreso

Tags: python

estaba creando un pequeño BOT para twitter, el resultado deseado es mostrar el progreso de lo que queda de temporada de Fortnite y necesitaría una pequeña ayuda.

Está sería la imagen "progressbar.png"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y mi problema es que no consigo que la barra de progreso naranja sea semi transparente (Cambiar la opacidad):

¿Cómo podria resolver este problema?

```
 with Image.open(f'{file_path}{progress_frame_file}') as img:
        progress_bar_amount = 43 + (percent*11.11)
        img1 = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
        transparent_area = (42,109,100,200)
        mask=Image.new('L', img.size,  color=255) #Si pongo esto al 50 se pone el fondo semi transparente
        
        draw=ImageDraw.Draw(mask) 
        #img1.rectangle(transparent_area)
        img.putalpha(mask)
        img1.rectangle([(progress_bar_amount, 255),(42, 109)], fill=bar_color) #Esta es la parte del progreso
        print('Added bar and created image')
        img.save(f'{file_path}progressbar.png')
```

Esta es una parte del código para que el progreso sea semi transparente pero no consigo hacerlo.

Lo que si consigo, es hacer el fondo semi transparente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero la barra no.

A ver si alguien me podría ayudar

¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: ¿Dónde asignas el color a `bar_color`? Creo que es ahí donde deberías darle al color una componente alpha para la opacidad

Comment: @abulafia así hice pero me sigue tirando error: https://i.imgur.com/wSuFcX9.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El truco se basa en dos puntos clave:

1. El color de relleno de la barra debe ser una tupla con 4 valores, siendo el cuarto el "canal alpha", es decir, la opacidad del color. 255 es completamente opaco, 0 es completamente transparente.
2. La superficie en que vayas a dibujar el rectángulo debe haber sido creada con `ImageDraw.Draw()` especificando el modo "RGBA" (por defecto si no lo pones usaría "RGB" y la componente alpha del color sería ignorada)

Aplicando estas cosas a un ejemplo similar al tuyo (no tenía tu imagen así que he creado otra usando una IA), y mejorando algunas cosas para que el tamaño de la barra se adapte al tamaño de la imagen  en lugar de tener que usar "números mágicos", el código podría quedar así:

```
from PIL import ImageDraw, Image
 
percent = 80  # Porcentaje de progreso
bar_color = (200, 120, 40, 180) # Color naranja semitransparente

with Image.open('test.png') as img:
    # Obtenemos las dimensiones de la imagen para colocar la barra
    # en coordenadas relativas a su tamaño
    w, h = img.size
    padding = 5
    transparent_area = [int(n) for n in (.10*w, .25*h, .90*w, .75*h)]
    progress_bar_length = percent/100*(transparent_area[2]-transparent_area[0]) - padding*2
    progress_bar_corners = (transparent_area[0]+padding, transparent_area[1]+padding, 
                            transparent_area[0] + progress_bar_length, transparent_area[3]-padding)
    
    # Preparamos la superficie en la que vamos a dibujar, tipo RGBA
    img1 = ImageDraw.Draw(img, "RGBA")

    # Pintamos primero el rectángulo de líneas blancas que delimita la zona de la barra de progreso
    # Observa que también he usado aquí un color de 4 componentes, blanco semitransparente
    img1.rectangle(transparent_area, fill = (255, 255, 255, 128))
    # Y ahora la parte naranja que cubre el porcentaje necesario
    img1.rectangle(progress_bar_corners, fill=bar_color)
    print('Added bar and created image')
    img.save(f'progressbar.png')
```

Resultado (la imagen era de 796x192)

[image: Resultado]